# search for availble bluetooth devices android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Iv'e looked around and i couldn't find any good and understadable answers on how to get a list of availble bluetooth devices in android studio java so if anyone can either point me to a good answer or post one here thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices

It is explained simple